# Is it possible to use Scrollspy in Wordpress?

Tags: scrollspy

I'm trying to link my fixed in page navigation menu with something like scrollspy. Because I have made a singlepage website out of a multipage website this is not something the theme supports.

Is there a way to do something like this by editing the code in Wordpress?

The url is: www.testchannel.nl

Thanks a lot!